# Generate square symmetric matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I have a matrix in R as follows:

```
dat <- matrix(c(2,3,5,7,8,4), ncol = 6)
colnames(dat) <- c("A(1,1)", "A(1,2)", "A(1,3)", "A(2,2)", "A(2,3)", "A(3,3)")
```

How can I create a square symmetric matrix based on an `apply` function that has the following form:

```
A(1,1) A(1,2) A(1,3)
A(2,1) A(2,2) A(2,3)
A(3,1) A(3,2) A(3,3)
```

Note that `A(1,2)=A(2,1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't based on `apply` but it shows how you can use `lower.tri` and `upper.tri` to create a symmetric matrix given a vector of elements. It shows the 3x3 case, but will easily generalize to larger `n`:

```
dat <- matrix(rep(0,9),nrow = 3)
dat[lower.tri(dat,diag = TRUE)] <- c(2,3,5,7,8,4)
dat[upper.tri(dat)] <- t(dat)[upper.tri(dat)]
print(dat)
```

Result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    5
[2,]    3    7    8
[3,]    5    8    4
```

Comment: @nickolakis The first line could be changed to `dat <- matrix(rep(0,n^2),nrow = n)`. Nothing else needs to be changed (other than the fact that the vector in the second line would have length `n*(n+1)/2`). If you don't know `n` but simply have a vector of the requisite length then it would be trickier since you would need to solve a quadratic equation to find `n` given `n*(n+1)/2`.

Comment: thanks, that seems to works perfectly. Can you provide the code for implementing the above for larger n? More precisely, how can I write in a general way the `c(2,3,5,7,8,4)`?